# Como recuperar a posição do ponteiro do mouse no android

Tags: java, android, android-studio

Tenho um accessibility service que captura eventos de toque na tela, e tenho um mouse USB conectado ao dispositivo Android, gostaria de saber como posso recuperar a posição do mouse na tela, ou ser notificado quando o mouse mudar sua posição.

encontrei setOnCapturedPointerListener, mas ele é API LVL 26, preciso na API 24.

```
myView.setOnCapturedPointerListener(new View.OnCapturedPointerListener() {
  @Override
  public boolean onCapturedPointer (View view, MotionEvent motionEvent) {
    // Get the coordinates required by your app
    float horizontalOffset = motionEvent.getX();
    // Use the coordinates to update your view and return true if the event was
    // successfully processed
    return true;
  }
});
```

Comment: encontrei myView.setOnCapturedPointerListener(new View.OnCapturedPointerListener() {
  @Override
  public boolean onCapturedPointer (View view, MotionEvent motionEvent) {
    // Get the coordinates required by your app
    float horizontalOffset = motionEvent.getX();
    // Use the coordinates to update your view and return true if the event was
    // successfully processed
    return true;
  }
});

porem nao funciona na API 24.

Comment: Por favor, não adicione "Resolvido" no título. Sei que é prática comum em muitos fóruns, mas aqui funciona diferente. No caso, [vc mesmo pode responder](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer), basta adicionar uma resposta abaixo (no campo "Sua resposta"). Em seguida, basta [aceitar a resposta](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/1078/112052), que o próprio site já indicará que o problema está resolvido